# Compiling ruby from source

Tags: ruby

Trying to compile ruby 2.2 on ubuntu 14.04 just for fun (please don't mention rvm, i know about it). While running make I receive such an error:

```
linking shared-object fiddle.so
/usr/bin/ld: ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a(raw_api.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against      `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

I've already tried to pass `-fPIC` to `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` variable in configure phase as suggested in error message, but got the same result.

Comment: Maybe this is a bug. Have you checked?

Comment: And how rvm compiles this version of ruby if it contains bug?

Comment: RVM does a lot of patching to work around known issues when compiling on certain platforms. I do not know how it handles Ruby 2.2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: I see, didn't know that it is so unstable. So how can I check if this is a bug?

Comment: have you installed `build-essential` packages?

Comment: yes, i've installed it